# search based on another document's content in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have Elasticsearch documents like

```
2017-10-30T22:31:32 {"msg":"start","query_id":"d84c4772","details":"sometext"}
2017-10-30T22:31:33 {"msg":"end", "query_id":"d84c4772","duration":"0.512"}
```

Each pair represents start and stop of certain process. `query_id` is unique value for each pair (i.e. should be twice only throughout all documents, it is shortened here just for example)

How can I find (using Elasticsearch) broken pair, that is document where the second pair (or first) is missing?

Updated: this is how the docs look like in `_search`:

```
  {
    "_index" : "dump_log",
    "_type" : "default",
    "_id" : "AV9vm0W3E9w_DiFlsabN",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "@timestamp" : "2017-10-30T06:25:02.355381",
      "@message" : {
          "msg" : "end",
          "query_id" : "d84c4772",
          "duration" : "0.512"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "dump_log",
    "_type" : "default",
    "_id" : "AV9vm0W3E9w_DiFlsabO",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "@timestamp" : "2017-10-30T06:25:02.356364",
      "@message" : {
          "details" : "sometext",
          "query_id" : "d84c4772",
          "msg" : "start"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It is not clear what is the actual document in ES, is it a single field with the values liked posted or `msg`, `query_id` etc are separate fields. If the latter then you can aggregate terms on query_id and then have a min_bucket or bucket_selector aggs to filter out buckets that have two documents. The performance of this approach is limited though.

Comment: Or even better - you can do terms on query_id, sort=_count ascending, this will bring you all the query_id with one document first.

Comment: @khachik the doks example added. Sorry, I'm newbie with ES, could you elaborate, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My simple and best approach is to aggregate on `query_id` with ascending order on `_count` for each bucket:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations":{
    "queries":{
      "terms":{
        "field": "query_id",
        "order":{
          "_count": "asc"
        },
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You will get an ordered list of buckets for each `query_id`.
Because its ordered at ascending order, the first buckets would have (if there are broken pairs) `"doc_count" : 1`.
If there are more then 10 broken pairs, you'll need to increase the size to see more broken pairs.

If you would like the actually see the broken document, use [Top Hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggregation:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations":{
    "queries":{
      "terms":{
        "field": "query_id",
        "order":{
          "_count": "asc"
        },
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggregations":{
        "broken_pair_document":{
          "top_hits":{
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```